# Alternative of JsonView in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

`@JsonView` helping me to filter out certain fields in output data dynamically. But before it filtering out all the queries have been executed.

I want to ignore the fields before querying it from database in order to avoid unnecessary queries to association tables.(`@JsonIgnore` works in this way. But it is not dynamic). Please help me out

Comment: provide some code samples your already tried.. and mention entities with your decorated annotations..

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections
I used `Spring data jpa projections` for that.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic filtering you could use a little addon i wrote for jackson:

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

This should kick in before issuing related table queries.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative that I use to replace some situations in which JsonView is being used only as a filter of the data that would be returned by an API, without reducing the query load on the database, is the use of projections and spring data have very good support, here's an example:

Using JsonView

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(View.NamesOnly.class)
    private String firstName;

    @JsonView(View.NamesOnly.class)
    private String lastName;
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
@JsonView(View.NamesOnly.class)
public ResponseEntity<Person> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return personRepository.findById(id)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Using Projection

```
public interface NamesOnly {

    String getFirstName();

    String getLastName();
}

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

   @Query(" select p from Person p where p.id = :id")
   Optional<NamesOnly> findByIdNames(Long id);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "projection")
public ResponseEntity<NamesOnly> findByIdNames(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return personRepository.findByIdNames(id)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Here is a complete example: https://github.com/pedrobacchini/spring-data-projection